# Why are not all the Conv2D weights of my tflite model in Int8 after conversion with dynamic range quantization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization, dtype

I have a Keras model and follow the [Post-training dynamic range quantization guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quant) to convert it to a tflite model. Upon inspection with [Netron](https://netron.app/), however, I am confused: Some of the Conv2D layers of the model use weights of type Int8, while others still use Float32. I cannot find any documentation on why only some of the weights might be quantized. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The code I used to convert the model is

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(5, None, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((3, 3), padding='same'),
])
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the model, and also for example which layers use int8 and which still use float32.

Comment: I've added code for an example model.

Answer (score 0):

TFLite skips quantizing layers with less than 1024 elements weights with dynamic quantization. I managed to force it to 128 by modifying quantization_config.h and rebuilding the package.